# Box API filter records based on created_by Box UserId field

Tags: box-api, box

The current folder listing API call responds with all the contents/items of folder. I have a requirement to filter the contents of a folder based on created_by field

Can you kindly let me know if this is already supported in BOX api calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported. You can use the [Search API](https://box-content.readme.io/#searching-for-content) to find content that is *owned* by a particular user, but not *created* by a particular user. Due to Box's collaboration model you cannot infer anything about creation from ownership, or vice-versa. As such, your only option is to [get the folder items](https://box-content.readme.io/#get-a-folders-items) and perform the filtering client-side.